# How to hide ViewBag in asp.net MVC3 razor View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I am rendering a new view from some view(say mainView) by using `Html.ActionLink("","",new{id=packageID})`

and my controller action(ActionLink passing control to) look like 

`public ActionResult editChecks(int packageID) 
        {return View();}`

Now at Rendered View("editChecks") i want to hide packageID so that i can use it(by passing it to another controller action) on another action by any means
i.e I am using form inside View("editChecks") which is submitting data to some action say(action2)

---

Presently I am using this in my view("editChecks")
and `string pid = Request.Form["packageID"];` at my controller action(need packageID) is this works fine for long run??? Or is there any alternate i should go for???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare any expected parameters in the method. You can also declare a default if it is not supplied `String packageID = "0"`

EDIT: your question is confusing. If you want to access it on the view, use viewbag.

```
public ActionResult action2(Int32 packageID) {

  // can use packageID here

 // Or make it accessable on the view
 ViewBag.PackageID = packageID;
  return View();
}
```

On the view you can access this by typing

```
@ViewBag.PackageID
```

Though I question why your packageID is a `String` in some cases. Should you not be using `Int32`?

EDIT: Going on your comments,

```
@Html.Hidden("PackageID", (Int32)@ViewBag.PackageID)
```

Will have the attribute on the page, hidden. And will be passed to any called submit (assuming within the form) as the name "PackageID"

Comment: I don't want to Display value passed by controller action to view rather i need that value at the same view in hidden format(so that value is hidden to the end user). And i am passing value to view by using ViewData dictionary(@ViewBag.PackageID)

Comment: Like @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.PackageID) is used for

Comment: Then just do `@Html.Hidden("PackageID", @ViewBag.PackageID)` This is the same as above, but without being attached to a model. i.e. you can assign it anything.

Comment: That does not work for me, I'm not sure how that is valid  ...@Html.Hidden("PackageID", @ViewBag.PackageID)  you should have to cast it like this @Html.Hidden("PackageID", (object)ViewBag.PackageID)

Comment: Why did you accept this answer? Does it work? Because it doesn't work for me